# File Name Too long error while reading a pcap file using subprocess.call

Tags: subprocess, pcap, tcpdump

I am new to using subprocess calls. Please help me in figuring out the issue in following script..

I am trying to write a new PCAP file (filter1.pcap) that would contain only packets from a specific IP address (ipadd) from a big set of packets from various IP addresses contained in a larger PCAP file(superset.pcap)

The error is: OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long

The code is as follows:

```
from subprocess import *
pcapfile = rdpcap("superset.pcap") 
ipadd = "192.168.1.1"              
fileout = "filter1.pcap"           
command = "sudo tcpdump -w %s -r %s src %s" %(fileout,pcapfile,ipadd)
subprocess.call( [command] )
```

BTW the below command in Linux works perfectly fine:

```
sudo tcpdump -w filter1.pcap -r superset.pcap src 192.168.1.1
```

Any help would be great !!

Thank you,
cks

Comment: Try changing pcapfile = rdpcap("superset.pcap") to pcap = "superset.pcap"    It looks like you're opening the file with scapy first, and then feeding the output to tcpdump, which will fail.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. Yes that was the issue !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved.. There was a logical error here. I was reading the complete PCAP file using rdpcap and passing the value to tcpdump. So tcpdump was reading the complete file itself as the file name.

I changed the code as below and it's working now !

```
import os.path
pcapfile = "superset.pcap"
ipadd = "192.168.1.1"         
fileout = "filter1.pcap"           
command = "sudo tcpdump -w %s -r %s src %s" %(fileout,pcapfile,ipadd)
os.system(command)
```